# Removal and delete of duplicate records in my table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I have this table:

```
id  |  Name  | Age
==================
1   | AAA    | 22
1   | AAA    | 22
2   | BBB    | 33
2   | BBB    | 33
2   | BBB    | 33
3   | CCC    | 44
4   | DDD    | 55
```

I need to delete from this table all the duplicate records and leave only one record.

The table will looks like this:

```
id  |  Name  | Age
==================
1   | AAA    | 22
2   | BBB    | 33
3   | CCC    | 44
4   | DDD    | 55
```

I work with SQL Server CE for Mobile

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An easy way in SQL Server is to use an updatable CTE:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*,
             row_number(*) over (partition by id, name, age) as seqnum
      from t
    )
delete todelete where seqnum > 1;
```

Alas, that doesn't work in SQL Server CE.  Because your rows have no unique identifier, I think you need to create a temporary table and use a method like this:

```
create table temp_t (
    id int,
    name varchar(255),
    age int
   );

insert into temp_t select distinct * from t;

delete t;

insert into t select * from temp_t;
```

Another method uses an extra column instead of an extra table:

```
alter table t add tokeep int;

insert into t(id, name, age, tokeep)
    select distinct id, name, age, 1
    from t;

delete from t where tokeep is null;

alter table drop column tokeep;
```